# An error occurred downloading the following resource: CRRuntime_32bit_13_0_18.msi?

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

After published the project from c# windows forms and try setup , I got this error :

I checked the website solutions but its not clear how to solve it from project properties this is the error cannot download the files :
An error occurred downloading the following resource:
http://downloads.businessobjects.com/akdlm/crnetruntime/clickonce/CRRuntime_32bit_13_0_18.msi

```
The following properties have been set:
Property: [AdminUser] = true {boolean}
Property: [InstallMode] = HomeSite {string}
Property: [NTProductType] = 1 {int}
Property: [ProcessorArchitecture] = AMD64 {string}
Property: [VersionNT] = 10.0.0 {version}
Running checks for package 'Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5.2 (x86 and x64)', phase BuildList
Reading value 'Release' of registry key 'HKLM\Software\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v4\Full'
Read integer value 528372
Setting value '528372 {int}' for property 'DotNet45Full_Release'
Reading value 'v4' of registry key 'HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\OS Integration'
Read integer value 1
Setting value '1 {int}' for property 'DotNet45Full_OSIntegrated'
The following properties have been set for package 'Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5.2 (x86 and x64)':
Property: [DotNet45Full_OSIntegrated] = 1 {int}
Property: [DotNet45Full_Release] = 528372 {int}
Running checks for command 'DotNetFX452\NDP452-KB2901907-x86-x64-AllOS-ENU.exe'
Result of running operator 'ValueEqualTo' on property 'InstallMode' and value 'HomeSite': true
Result of checks for command 'DotNetFX452\NDP452-KB2901907-x86-x64-AllOS-ENU.exe' is 'Bypass'
Running checks for command 'DotNetFX452\NDP452-KB2901907-x86-x64-AllOS-ENU.exe'
Result of running operator 'ValueEqualTo' on property 'InstallMode' and value 'HomeSite': true
Result of checks for command 'DotNetFX452\NDP452-KB2901907-x86-x64-AllOS-ENU.exe' is 'Bypass'
Running checks for command 'DotNetFX452\NDP452-KB2901954-Web.exe'
Result of running operator 'ValueNotEqualTo' on property 'InstallMode' and value 'HomeSite': false
Result of running operator 'ValueGreaterThanEqualTo' on property 'DotNet45Full_Release' and value '379893': true
Result of checks for command 'DotNetFX452\NDP452-KB2901954-Web.exe' is 'Bypass'
Running checks for command 'DotNetFX452\NDP452-KB2901954-Web.exe'
Result of running operator 'ValueNotEqualTo' on property 'InstallMode' and value 'HomeSite': false
Result of running operator 'ValueGreaterThanEqualTo' on property 'DotNet45Full_Release' and value '379893': true
Result of checks for command 'DotNetFX452\NDP452-KB2901954-Web.exe' is 'Bypass'
'Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5.2 (x86 and x64)' RunCheck result: No Install Needed
Running checks for package 'SAP Crystal Reports Runtime Engine for .NET Framework', phase BuildList
Reading value 'CRRuntime32Version' of registry key 'HKLM\SOFTWARE\SAP BusinessObjects\Crystal Reports for .NET Framework 4.0\Crystal Reports'
Unable to read registry value
Not setting value for property 'CRRuntime32Version'
Reading value 'CRRuntime64Version' of registry key 'HKLM\SOFTWARE\SAP BusinessObjects\Crystal Reports for .NET Framework 4.0\Crystal Reports'
Unable to read registry value
Not setting value for property 'CRRuntime64Version'
The following properties have been set for package 'SAP Crystal Reports Runtime Engine for .NET Framework':
Running checks for command 'Crystal Reports for .NET Framework 4.0\CRRuntime_32bit_13_0_18.msi'
Result of running operator 'ValueNotEqualTo' on property 'ProcessorArchitecture' and value 'Intel': true
Result of checks for command 'Crystal Reports for .NET Framework 4.0\CRRuntime_32bit_13_0_18.msi' is 'Bypass'
Running checks for command 'Crystal Reports for .NET Framework 4.0\CRRuntime_64bit_13_0_18.msi'
Result of running operator 'ValueNotEqualTo' on property 'ProcessorArchitecture' and value 'AMD64': false
Skipping ByPassIf because Property 'CRRuntime64Version' was not defined
Result of running operator 'ValueEqualTo' on property 'AdminUser' and value 'false': false
Skipping FailIf because Property 'Version9x' was not defined
Result of running operator 'VersionLessThan' on property 'VersionNT' and value '5.00': false
Result of checks for command 'Crystal Reports for .NET Framework 4.0\CRRuntime_64bit_13_0_18.msi' is 'Install'
'SAP Crystal Reports Runtime Engine for .NET Framework' RunCheck result: Install Needed
EULA for components 'SAP Crystal Reports Runtime Engine for .NET Framework' was accepted.
Copying files to temporary directory "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Temp\VSDFBB4.tmp\"
Downloading files to "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Temp\VSDFBB4.tmp\"
(11/23/2020 05:34:57 PM) Downloading 'Crystal Reports for .NET Framework 4.0\CRRuntime_32bit_13_0_18.msi' from 'http://downloads.businessobjects.com/akdlm/crnetruntime/clickonce/CRRuntime_32bit_13_0_18.msi' to 'C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Temp\VSDFBB4.tmp\'
Download completed at 11/23/2020 05:35:01 PM
Downloading failed with HRESULT=-2146697202
```

[image]

How to solve this error please before some days its working fine ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I worked around this for last 3 days and found the solution :

1- go to project properties then publish tab.

2- click prerquisites and uncheck SAP crystal reports runtime Engine for .NET Framework.

[image]

3- publish the project and install it without crystal report runtime .

4- I'm using Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 update 3 .

5- Download crystal report runtime SP 20 64 bit Version 13.0.20 compatible with VS 2015 from the following link :
https://www.tektutorialshub.com/crystal-reports/how-to-download-and-install-crystal-report-runtime/

6- after download and setup crystal report runtime engine , i can run and use my reports.

Hope this will help the others for sure a lot of developers faced this issue.

Answer (score 1):

SAP recently removed those files.

You can host them on your own web site and update the product.xml file to point at the correct location.

Comment: you mean I can download the files on my hosting site can you tell me the steps with example thank you so much

Comment: They are moved to https://origin.softwaredownloads.sap.com/public/site/index.html though even if I update the product.xml file to point at the new location, the download fails. But if i use the same url that the error shows (the updated location) in a browser, the download works.